# unable to "java" , "javac" etc. commands on terminal directly and two versions of jdk?

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk, oracle

I usually use eclipse , but I said "lets do some fantasy" to myself and things happened. I tried to use terminal command `javac` at first. I got

```
 The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:

* default-jdk
* ecj
* gcj-5-jdk
* openjdk-8-jdk-headless
* gcj-4.8-jdk
* gcj-4.9-jdk
* openjdk-9-jdk-headless

Try: sudo apt install (selected package)
```

I already installed jre8 and jdk8 manually from oracle's website (standard edition) and I'm making programs with eclipse already. Then I typed `java -version` and the answer was

```
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)
```

which is not what i installed manually. Then I used `locate -br ^javac$` and got two locations (not a surprise). So:

1. I can use `javac` only with the path to where I installed jdk manually, but I wanna use commands without path, just directly . Is that possible (if yes then how ?
2. It seems like I have two java versions. Does that cause any problem? If it does, tell me how to fix please (I prefer eliminating openjdk9)

Comment: please see updated answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose your default java by running `update-alternatives`:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java

There are 5 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java              1091      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1081      manual mode
* 3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java              1091      manual mode
  4            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_91                         100       manual mode
  5            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java                100       manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Now to change your version simple `type a number` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or to keep the default, just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Do the same for the compiler :

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

And make your choice. Now one can also use a better command `update-java-alternatives` as recommended by *Chai*.

Now assuming you have these *java packages* installed:

```
java-9-oracle
java-8-openjdk-amd64
jdk1.8.0_91
```

And I want the `java-9-oracle` version, then I will simply run:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s <java_name>

sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-9-oracle
```

This would create all the needed links to my desired java version.

Now in the light that you placed *java* in a different location we will use `update-alternatives --install` to let it know where our java is.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/share/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java 1
```

And for the compiler `javac` the same

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/share/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/javac 1
```

Source:
`man update-java-alternatives`

Comment: `update-java-alternatives` is better, as it changes all the binaries (`javac`, `javap`, `jar`, etc).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers ! Unfortunately my problem is not solved . When i downloaded java manually , intructions were telling me to unzip .tar.gz file in any directory  i want to install java . so my directory is "/usr/share/java/jdk1.8.0_121" . but when i try your codes , im receiving an error as 
"update-java-alternatives: directory does not exist: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_121"
and with other code , im only viewing folders under "/usr/lib/jvm/". what shoul i do now?  @Chai

Comment: Ok let me update the answer so you can add it with `update-alternatives --install`

Comment: @Letitbe please see updated answer...